# php how to define a variable with special characters

Tags: php

I am creating a variable as:

```
  $sHTML_Content2 =
    "
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    ";
```

so I am trying to print this to a file: `FWRITE($handle,$$sHTML_Content1);`

that file handler is a html page which I am displaying to the console.
I am not getting why when I added the above table I am not able to create the html page.

is there any mistake i am doing with the HTML_Content1 variable that it is not able to write?

Comment: What special characters? I don't see any in the variable name or its contents.

Comment: sHTML_Content1 is the variable name. I am passing it to the file handler

Comment: You're mixing up `$sHTML_Content1` and `$sHTML_Content2`.

Comment: fwrite can't be in caps.

Comment: @Kishore: Could you make it more clear? Which variable you are assigning and which variable is assumed to write data to file?

Comment: fwrite with caps is working for me simple text. only when I keep a variable as shown in the example I see this Error.

Comment: I am using : $sHTML_Content2 . and the variable is : FWRITE($handle,$sHTML_Content2);

Comment: @Kishor: Show the full code of file handling activitiy

Comment: If $sHTML_Content2 like: $sHTML_Header = "<html><head><title>Test an html page</title></head><body>"; 
I see that it is writing to the HTML page which Ia m creating dynamically: FWRITE($handle, $sHTML_Content);  but If I try to do this for a table the HTML page is not getting created

Comment: $sHTML_Header = "<html><head><title>Test an html page</title></head><body>"; 
$sHTML_Content2 =
"
<table>
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
"; 
$sHTML_Footer =  "</body></html>"; 

FWRITE($handle, $sHTML_Header);
FWRITE($handle,$sHTML_Content2);
FWRITE($handle, $sHTML_Footer);

==
This handler is a html page.

Issue is : If content is text it is getting printed but if I keep a table it does not create it 
in the html page.

Comment: Is there a way to find the Errors in a php

Comment: @Cole - while I agree that fwrite should not be written in caps, PHP is case insensitive in function and method names.

Comment: but still I am not getting what I am missing

Comment: @gnif oops... really? I was pretty sure it was case sensitive but I'm quite wrong. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 3):

you have double $$ signs there. maybe it's causing a problem.

```
fwrite($handle,$sHTML_Content1);
```

Comment: do you receive any error message? can you provide full code of file handling?

Answer (score 1):

If I get it correct you are using wrong variable name to write to a file.

You are assigning the table with  `$sHTML_Content2` variable and when writing to a file you are using different variable.

```
fwrite($handle,$sHTML_Content2);
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo. I mean Content2 only. Actually I have content1 also a table. Issue is still there

Comment: @Kishore: Remove one  `$` sign in the front of the variable

Comment: $sHTML_Header = "<html><head><title>Test an html page</title></head><body>"; 
$sHTML_Content2 =
"
<table>
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
"; 
$sHTML_Footer =  "</body></html>"; 

FWRITE($handle, $sHTML_Header);
FWRITE($handle,$sHTML_Content2);
FWRITE($handle, $sHTML_Footer);

==
This handler is a html page.

Issue is : If content is text it is getting printed but if I keep a table it does not create it 
in the html page.